# How to generate DDL by Persistence.generateSchema()?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="safety" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/MyDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="create.ddl"/>
      <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="safety"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my persistence.xml. How can I generate DB schema by Persistence.generateSchema()?

```
public class SchemaGenerator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //adding some properties
        Persistence.generateSchema("safety", properties);
    }
}
```

It gives me this error : org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:/jdbc/MyDataSource].

But, it does not have to connect my database as I just need to generate ddl.

Comment: I looked at the link below. But it does not work in my case. https://github.com/hantsy/ee7-sandbox/wiki/jpa-scripts

Comment: You can comment out the jta-data-source from persistence.xml for a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the property `connection.provider_class` to `org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl`. That way he is not trying to load the JNDI source.

This is my `generation.properties` I use for offline schema generation with the *Ant Hibernate Tool* :

```
hibernate.dialect=...
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl
javax.persistence.validation.mode=ddl, callback
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
```

Comment: I've got this error. Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl] as strategy [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

Comment: In that case I guess your Hibernate version does not include that provider - which version are you using?

Comment: If I remove jta-data-source from persistence.xml, it gives me this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:61).    Obviously, my library has that class. I am using hibernate 4.3.10.Final.

Comment: You should check, why he is calling `getConnection`. Can't see that from your stacktrace snippet.